# How to display JSON file on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm starting to learn javascript. I want to display the first and last names and relation value on an html page when a user click a button. I have a simple JSON file called FamilyAndFriends.json:

```
    {
    "people":[{"fname":"Adam",
        "lname":"Schmitt",
            "relation":"Brother",
            "relationid":"1"
        },
        {"fname":"Andrew",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Brother",
            "relationid":"1"
        },
        {"fname":"Jenna",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Wife",
            "relationid":"2"
        },
        {"fname":"Gary",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Father",
            "relationid":"3"
        },
        {"fname":"Judy",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Mother",
            "relationid":"4"            
        },
        {"fname":"Justin",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Friend",
            "relationid":"5"            
        },
        {"fname":"Billy",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Friend",
            "relationid":"5"             
        },
        {"fname":"Robbie",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Friend",
            "relationid":"5"             
        },
        {"fname":"Dylan",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Friend",
            "relationid":"5"             
        },
        {"fname":"Zach",
        "lname":"Name",
            "relation":"Friend",
            "relationid":"5"             
        }]
}
```

I tried searching and it seems a lot of people suggest jquery but we are not to jquery at the moment. How would I be able to get the info from my .json file and display it in my html file when the user clicks? 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Has your class covered **AJAX** or **XMLHttpRequest()** yet?  That would be the standard way of getting the data *into* your page *dynamically*.  If not, there are ways to hardcode/place the data into the page to work with.  A full answer will need to know.

Comment: Yeah he should us it. I'm just still trying to understand it I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML code:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Just keep your JSON data in a variable (or) separate file as 'FamilyAndFriends.json'.

```
var data = {
"people":[{"fname":"Adam",
    "lname":"Schmitt",
        "relation":"Brother",
        "relationid":"1"
    },
    {"fname":"Andrew",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Brother",
        "relationid":"1"
    },
    {"fname":"Jenna",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Wife",
        "relationid":"2"
    },
    {"fname":"Gary",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Father",
        "relationid":"3"
    },
    {"fname":"Judy",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Mother",
        "relationid":"4"            
    },
    {"fname":"Justin",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Friend",
        "relationid":"5"            
    },
    {"fname":"Billy",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Friend",
        "relationid":"5"             
    },
    {"fname":"Robbie",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Friend",
        "relationid":"5"             
    },
    {"fname":"Dylan",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Friend",
        "relationid":"5"             
    },
    {"fname":"Zach",
    "lname":"Name",
        "relation":"Friend",
        "relationid":"5"             
    }]
 };
```

Example for external JSON using javascript:

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('GET', '/my/url', true); // YOUR EXTERNAL JSON URL

 request.onload = function() {
     if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
     // Success!
         var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
         var link;
         for (var t = 0; t < data.people.length; t++){
             link = document.createElement("a"+t);
             var ulist = document.getElementById("list");
             var newItem = document.createElement("li");
             newItem.appendChild(link);
             ulist.appendChild(newItem);
             link.textContent = 'First Name: '+data.people[t].fname + ', Last Name: ' +data.people[t].lname;
             link.setAttribute('data-ind', t); // ADDED A DATA ATTRIBUTE TO STORE A INDEX VALUE
            if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function'){
                 (function (_td) {
                      link.addEventListener('click', function(){
                      var indexId = this.getAttribute('data-ind'); //GETTING DATA ATTRIBUTE VALUE
                      indexId =  parseInt(indexId); //PARSE FROM STRING TO INTEGER
                      alert(data.people[indexId].relation); // YOU WILL GET THE ACTUAL RELATION VALUE.

                  });
               })(link);
     }
  }
     } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

     }
 };

 request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
 };

 request.send();
```

Example for Internal JSON using javascript:

```
 var link;
 for (var t = 0; t < data.people.length; t++){
    link = document.createElement("a"+t);
    var ulist = document.getElementById("list");
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.appendChild(link);
    ulist.appendChild(newItem);
    link.textContent = 'First Name: '+data.people[t].fname + ', Last Name: ' +data.people[t].lname;
    link.setAttribute('data-ind', t); // ADDED A DATA ATTRIBUTE TO STORE A INDEX VALUE
    if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function'){
        (function () {
            link.addEventListener('click', function(){
                var indexId = this.getAttribute('data-ind'); //GETTING DATA ATTRIBUTE VALUE
                indexId =  parseInt(indexId); //PARSE FROM STRING TO INTEGER
                alert(data.people[indexId].relation); // YOU WILL GET THE ACTUAL RELATION VALUE.

            });
        })(link);
     }
  }
```

Result will be like below when you click the first list:

```
Brother
```

**Rock it!**

Comment: So, if I am understanding this correctly, I can't have the json information in a .json file right? It doesn't seem to like the var data in my .json file. I would need to add the info to the HTML right?  Is there a way to complete this by using a separate .json instead of putting it in the html file?

Comment: even you keep your .json file as separate. just you have to use below code for Jquery or Javascript(vanila):
Jquery: 
`$.getJSON('/my/url', function(data) {

});`

Comment: Javascript:
`var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();`

Comment: ah ok. I'll give it a shot. One last question where does the _td come from? Its function (_td). When I put the code in it gives me a warning saying unused.

Comment: oh, (_td) just kept for receiving a current list in the console while click, you can remove it now.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Looks like it works and populates the list. I'm going to mess around with it more and see how I can make the list disappear.  Thanks again

Comment: Welcome Mr. Matthew :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
    <title>JSON Basic</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Display JSON file on HTML page:</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button onclick="displayInfo()">Display</button>
    <script>
        var i;
        var peopleinfo = "";
        var people = [{
            "fname": "Adam",
            "lname": "Schmitt",
            "relation": "Brother",
            "relationid": "1"
        }, {
            "fname": "Andrew",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Brother",
            "relationid": "1"
        }, {
            "fname": "Jenna",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Wife",
            "relationid": "2"
        }, {
            "fname": "Gary",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Father",
            "relationid": "3"
        }, {
            "fname": "Judy",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Mother",
            "relationid": "4"
        }, {
            "fname": "Justin",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Friend",
            "relationid": "5"
        }, {
            "fname": "Billy",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Friend",
            "relationid": "5"
        }, {
            "fname": "Robbie",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Friend",
            "relationid": "5"
        }, {
            "fname": "Dylan",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Friend",
            "relationid": "5"
        }, {
            "fname": "Zach",
            "lname": "Name",
            "relation": "Friend",
            "relationid": "5"
        }];
        for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
          
            peopleinfo += people[i].fname + "<br>" + people[i].lname + "<br>" + people[i].relation + "<br>" + people[i].relationid + "<br><p>********</p>";
        }

        function displayInfo() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = peopleinfo;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Good try, but I think you are not understand the question clearly. whatever you did is very easy and straight forward.

Answer (score -2):

```
console.log($.parseJSON(yourJsonFile));
```

With this, you will have an object containing your JSON file information.

Comment: The question ruled out using jquery